# Alphabetically order new entries in an ArrayList using the compareTo method

Tags: java, string-comparison, compareto

I want to alphabetically order entries into an ArrayList directory called entries. I want as a new entry is added to the directory to be placed into an appropriate position in the ArrayList.

For example, if we have two entries already in the directory with surnames: "Beta" and "Cee" and we want to add a new entry that has surname: "Alpha",
"Alpha" should be placed first.

My question is, How can I overwrite the compareTo method to compare the two strings (String "one", and the other String that is passed into the method-"surname") alphabetically?

```
private ArrayList<Entry> entries=new ArrayList<>();

public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String number) {
    Entry entry=new Entry(surname,initial,number);

    if (surname == null || initial == null || number == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill all the required fields, [surname,initials,number]");
    else {
        boolean flag = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < entries.size(); x++) {
            String one= entries.get(x).getSurname();

            if (one.compareTo(surname)>0) {
                entries.add(x,entry);
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            entries.add(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion `ArrayList` is not a right choice for this situation, you seem to add the new `Entry` in the "correct" position according to the `compareTo` method defined in the `Entry` class.

So ideally a `TreeSet` should be used which basically maintains the ordering of the elements based on the `compareTo` defined in the `Entry` class which is the "default ordering".

```
class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
    private String surname;
    private String initial;
    private String number;

    Entry(String surname, String initial, String number){
        this.surname = surname;
        this.number =number;
        this.initial = initial;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry entry){
        return this.surname.compareTo(entry.surname);
    }
}
```

And the `addEntry` method should be simply:

```
private Set<Entry> entries = new TreeSet<>();

public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String number) {
        if (surname == null || initial == null || number == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please fill all the required fields, [surname,initials,number]");
        else {
            Entry entry=new Entry(surname,initial,number);
            entries.add(entry);
        }
 }
```

And if you really need an `List`, you can simply wrap the `TreeSet` instance in the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
List<Entry> list = new ArrayList(entries);
```

Comment: I implemented all of this but still, it does not alphabetically order the entries as it was required.

Comment: What is your `compareTo ` method, that you are using?

Comment: The one you wrote above

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: it worked, many thanks, it appears I had an upper case letter in a surname in one of my tests. Any ideas how I can implement the equalsignorecase method in the compareTo method?

Comment: Convert both to lower case: `this.surname.toLowerCase().compareTo(entry.surname.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 1):

```
String one= entries.get(x).toString();
```

in this line of code you are having `reference` of `Entry` object unless you have `overridden` `toString()` method. So from my guess you need to do this:

```
String one = entries.get(x).getSurname();
```

As you need to compare surnames get Surname of that entity then compare it to new Entity's surname. That will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your entry to any index in the your `ArrayList` and then sort the list using a stream

```
public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String number) {
    if (surname == null || initial == null || number == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Please fill all the required fields, [surname,initials,number]");
    }

    Entry entry=new Entry(surname,initial,number);
    entries.add(entry);

    entries = entries.stream()
                .map(eachEntry -> eachEntry.getSurname())
                .sorted((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```